# Are new SSL Certificates after patching Heartbleed?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, csr, heartbleed-bug

We've upgraded our servers and regenerated any cpanel / dovecot / ssh keys. 
do our customers also need to regenerate a CSR and SSL certificates?

I've not seen any information on this aspect of things.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread on Unix/Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123711/how-do-i-recover-from-the-heartbleed-bug-in-openssl),

> How do I fix the vulnerability?
> ...
> Generate new keys. This is necessary because the bug might have allowed an attacker to obtain the old private key. Follow the same procedure you used initially.

And [this answer on Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55075/does-heartbleed-mean-new-certificates-for-every-ssl-server/55087#55087):

> It means much more than just new certificates (or rather, new key pairs) for every affected server.
> ...
> Summarized from heartbleed.com (emphasis mine):
> ...
> What is leaked primary key material and how to recover?
>
> These are the crown jewels, the encryption keys themselves.

And [this thread on Serverfault SE](https://serverfault.com/questions/587329/heartbleed-what-is-it-and-what-are-options-to-mitigate-it):

> As noted on the Heartbleed site, appropriate reponse steps are broadly:
>
> 1. Patch vulnerable systems.
> 2. Regenerate new private keys.
> 3. Submit new CSR to your CA.
> 4. Obtain and install new signed certificate.
> 5. Revoke old certificates.

So yes, I strongly suggest you change any and all keys/certificates. I also recommend reading those threads in their entirety as well as some of the threads they reference. There's quite a bit of information on the bug spread across Security and Serverfault SEs.

Answer (score 1):

With Heartbleed it is possible to retrieve the private keys.

So, if you have been vulnerable, **yes**, it is strongly recommended that your customers change their private keys.